# Disable tooltips in material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

Is there any way to disable tooltips from material-table,

[image]

As shown in image,there is tooltips as: first page, also there are other tips for search and so on. Is there any way to disable all the tooltips, not the actual toolbars but the tooltips only?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2piiy

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I have included codesandbox link...please have a look

Comment: In your codesandbox you don't have `first page` written anywhere. Also, search is not a title, it is a placeholder.

Comment: @SinanYaman Hover over the arrows

Comment: It's inbuild toolbar title that I need to disable...@m4n0 yes exactly when we hover over arrows the toolbartitle appears which I want to disable.

Comment: I think you are talking about `tooltips`, that is the text you see when you hover over the arrows. Do you want to disable them or to translate them?

Comment: Yes @NicoE, I'm sorry...exactly I want to disable tooltips.

Comment: Hey @SivaPradhan have you tried the solution below? Did it worked for you? If not how have you addressed the issue?

Comment: @NicoE actually I wanted to disable the tooltip because useEffect was rendring data again and again which was messing with pagination and I thought it was only issue of tooltip. But to disable tooltip we have to do manually for every tool tip as mentioned.

Anyways, thank you for the solution. It will surely help in future if anyone want to disable for tooltip. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an option to specifically disable all `tooltips`, so as a workaround, to avoid having to override components and create your own, you could try to use `localization` with empty values.

For example, the first-page tooltip would be like this:

```jsx
      <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={data}
        title="Material Table - Title"
        localization={{
          pagination: {
            firstTooltip: ""
          }
        }}
      />
```

By doing these the `tooltip` won't be shown in the UI. Take a look at the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization) to see the list of texts that you could modify.

Hope that works for you!